# Creating Excel Macro for Formatting PDF Comment Text File

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba, macros

I am very new to excel, and think that this is a simple task, but need some help. I am trying to load a text file, which is the result of exporting a comment summary from a PDF, into Excel, and have excel read the file and format the data. The text file looks like this:
[Text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1bCg.png)

The comments on a specific page are listed underneath that page number, and there are sometimes multiple comments on each page. I am trying to make a macro that would format the content of the file like this: 
[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJTcW.png)

Any help is appreciated! Just looking for someone to guide me in the right direction as I have very little experience with macros/VBA

Comment: Are you able to export the comments in XML instead of text? If so, you should be able to open the XML file in Excel and it'll be formatted much better than just a text file. [These steps might help](https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/export-pdf-comments-to-excel/)

Comment: I can export it to an XML file, but when that's imported to Excel it gives me a complicated table that doesn't contain the info I need. So I figured that the text file would be the easiest way if I could find a way to march through it and sort the data as I go